# Embed OLEobject based on cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to embed an OLEObject (text file) in Excel, with the filename being derived from a particular cell. I can do this as a one off action but am now trying to make it work in a loop through all the cells in a column, finishing when it comes across an empty cell.

I can't seem to get the right syntax to make the If/Else loop work:

```
Sub Insert_Text_File()

Dim ol As OLEObject
Dim path As String
Dim file As String
Dim filenameinvisible As String
Dim rangeA As Range
Dim rangeD As Range

path = ActiveWorkbook.Path
file = Range(i,1).Value & "-Live" & ".txt"
Set rangeA = Range("A" & i)
Set rangeD = Range("D" & i)

For i = 2 To 200
    If Range("A" & i) <> "" Then
        Set ol = Worksheets("Inventory").OLEObjects.Add (Filename:= path & "\" & file, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, Height:=10)

        ol.Top =Range("D" & i).top

        ol.left=Range("D" & i).left

    End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: When I run the code I get an Error saying: Next without For

Comment: Check this line: file = Range(i,1).Value & "-Live" & ".txt". You have not initiliased i at this point. Also, Use Cell(i,1) instead of Range(i,1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem with your current approach is that your are assigning the value to the `path` variable only once - `file = Range(i,1).Value & "-Live" & ".txt"` before the loop increases `i`.

A better approach requiring less variables would be using a `for each` loop using a `cell` variable of `Range` type and relying on VBA to find the last row used rather than hard-coding 200 into the loop.

Try this approach and let us know if that has worked.

```
Sub Insert_Text_File()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim cell As Range

    ' loop each cell in column A 
    For Each cell In Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
         ' make sure the cell is NOT empty before doing any work
         If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then

            ' create and insert a new OleObject based on the path
            Dim ol As OLEObject
            ' ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & cell & "-Live.txt" will make the filename
            Set ol = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add( _
                                                Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & cell & "-Live.txt", _
                                                Link:=False, _
                                                DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
                                                Height:=10)
            ' align the OleObject with Column D - (0 rows, 3 columns to the right from column A)
            With ol
                .Top = cell.Offset(0, 3).Top
                .Left = cell.Offset(0, 3).Left
            End With
        End If
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh my god, that's a thing of beauty, works perfectly! Thankyou!  Now, I gotta just understand why it works! Thanks vba4all.

Comment: Thanks, what is it that you don't understand? I can explain

Comment: I understand the logic of what you've done, the comments are really helpful, it's more that I'm new to vba and so need to become more familiar with all the commands.  Working out exactly what you've done here, what each command means will be a good way for me to learn.