# Create checkboxes automatically

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to automatically create a checkbox in column A if there is data in Column B. (The reason is, that I have a huge list with more than 300 rows which will grow over time and this solution should be a permanent one)

```
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", Link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=24.75, Top:=75.75, Width:=12.75, Height:= _
    12.75).Select
```

Thats the code I`ve got already to create a checkbox.

I am not that familiar with VBA - I started only a couple of days ago working with makros.

How should I change it so the checkboxes are getting created automatically as soon as I put in some text into the cell next to it?

edit: the checkboxes should be named by numbers "Checkbox x" starting with 1. Also no captions needed..

Comment: What do you need to use checkboxes for? Could data-validation drop-down not be implemented? The reason I ask is just because adding checkboxes like this can end up very messy!

Comment: I'd stay away from checkboxes if possible, so far I got Excel to create the checkboxes as you put the text in but there seems to be another issue with the formula you included, so I'm looking into that atm.

Comment: That is what I thought. Ok, so I have this sheet with all this data and I added a button which does the follwoing: 
- creates a new sheet 
- names the sheet as the cell value of column b
- copies the template from the template sheet into that new sheet
- copies the data from the row with the sheet name into the new sheet

now I got the code to check if the checkbox in column a is ticket and wether it is or it is not it does export or not. 
But I can not create all those checkboxes manually...

Comment: what do you recommend as an alternative?

Comment: You could use Data-Validation to get "dropdown" checkbox-type inputs on your cells. You could couple this with worksheet_change events to trigger any special things you could do with a checkbox

Comment: I already use data validiation with those dropdown lists. But the reason for the checkbox is to choose which rows should get copied into the template to get printed out.

Comment: To be honest, I would use a *fake* checkbox. I mean, I got some teamworkers that love to *click* on checkboxes, and for me is a pain the head later to work with macros. So now my teamworkers just put some capital X in some cells, and that's their *checkbox*. It's clean, simple, and efective. And, indeed, a lot easier for me later on to use formulas or macros on cells with an X inside or not. You can combine this option with the data validation option, so only an X or nothing can be entered as a value in the cell. Is just an advice. Do what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

Using some of the code from this question - [vba macro to embed OLEobject based on cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911105/vba-macro-to-embed-oleobject-based):

```
Sub InsertToB()

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
         If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then

            Dim ol As OLEObject
            Set ol = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", _
                                                Link:=False, _
                                                DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
                                                Height:=10)
            With ol
                .Top = cell.Offset(0, 1).Top
                .Left = cell.Offset(0, 1).Left
                .Object.Caption = "Bob"
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

- The code loops in the active sheet and checks whether the cell in `A` is empty;
- Then adds a checkbox;
- The exact position of the checkbox is decided through `.Top` and `.Left`;

[image]

Comment: I think you switched the columns A and B.

Comment: @M.Douda - true, they are switched.

Comment: @Vityata that is awesome. Thank you! But how do I hide the captions?

Comment: Also there is one Problem, it works for the first time, but if I add rows later and rerun the macro it renames all checkboxes starting by the name of the last checkbox earlier (for example if I got 300 checkboxes before, the new first checkbox is 301)

Comment: @VincenzoKöstler - seems like a problem indeed, you have to find a way to change the Caption as well. I have tried `ol.Object.Caption = "Something"`, it accepts it as a caption but it does not change it.

Comment: @VincenzoKöstler - actually it works, if the file is saved and closed. See the update.

Comment: Thanks! Still, how do I prevent the makro from creating checkboxes twice? I thinkg the theoretical way would be to check if there is Data in Column B, and if, check if there is a checkbox in column A and if not, create a CB. But tbh I do not know how to do it in practice

Comment: @VincenzoKöstler - the easiest way is to write somewhere (let's say column C) some info, upon creating the checkbox. Then create the checkbox only if the value of column C is not present. Not exactly robust, but it would be quite ok, if you do it in another hidden workbook.

Comment: also I do not know why but it does not work for me with the captions

Comment: @VincenzoKöstler - save the file and close it. Then open it again.

Comment: @VincenzoKöstler - so you do not get "Bob" after running my code, saving as `xlsb` and openning again?

Comment: @VincenzoKöstler - strange. I get it.

Comment: @Vityata is there any other solution for disableing the caption? It cant be that difficult can it? But I cannot find anything about it...