# Is there a way to set the file path dynamically if i am trying to attach a file in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code I am trying to work on. I am new to Excel VBA.

```
    Sub Test1()
      Dim x As Integer
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
      NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
           For x = 1 To NumRows
         ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:= _
        "Filelocation\filename.extension" _
        , Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:="C:\Windows\Installer\{90160000-000F-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}\wordicon.exe", _
        IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:= _
        "Filelocation\filename.extension" _
        ).Select

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Next
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Here I want to attach the next file in the folder. 
As of now with this code, I can attach the same file multiple times.
My requirement is to attach different files in different cells as I move down.
I hope the question was clear :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911105/embed-oleobject-based-on-cell

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed OLEobject based on cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911105/embed-oleobject-based-on-cell)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sheet named `Control` which has the location of the files to be attached with a button with the below macro assigned to it.

```
Sub fileInsertionForRetest()
On Error GoTo er
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim NumRows As Long
    Worksheets("Retest").Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("G2").Select
    NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        For x = 1 To NumRows


           Range("B" & x + 1&).EntireRow.RowHeight = 60

            ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:= _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Control").Range("B2").Value & Range("A" & x + 1&).Value & ".docx", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
            IconFileName:="C:\Windows\Installer\{90160000-000F-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE}\wordicon.exe", _
            IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:=Range("A" & x + 1&).Value).Select

            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Done:
    MsgBox "All file were attached successfully"
    Exit Sub
er:
MsgBox "The following error occurred: " & err.Description
End Sub
```